# Doctrine relation to any object (any class)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating an entity class which represents a `MenuItem`. This can have a one-to-one relation with any class implementing `SluggableInterface`.

As the `MenuItem` should be able to relate to any `SluggableInterface` class (existing and future), I cannot specify a normal doctrine relation as there isn't a specific related entity.

I've come up with some possible solutions, but they have drawbacks:

1. Create an `ObjectReference` entity to hold the class name and id of the related object. This class would then have a `getObject()` method to construct and return the necessary object. **The drawback here is you can't (cleanly, at least) access doctrine from within the entity.**
2. Create an `object_reference` type to convert the object to a string containing the class name and id. **The issue again is accessing doctrine in the `Type` class to retrieve the object.**
3. I've not tried this one yet, but create a class listening to doctrine events, then checking for fields with a custom annotation, and do the Object->String and vice-versa conversion there.

Before I start investigating #3, does anyone know of a "proper" or alternative way to do this?

Comment: Consider using Inheritance Mapping for your Sluggable objects. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html.  You will need to add all Sluggable objects to the mapping table.  But that is the only real limit.  And you "might" be able to add new classes by using the metadata.

Comment: @Cerad; Class table inheritance may work, but as you say, the metadata could be an issue. I'm going to look into whether it's possible to avoid the DiscriminatorMap (e.g. writing actual entityname in the discriminator column, rather than a reference)

Comment: you could make some sort of content mapper where every sluggableInterface has a typeId and then check against a config file, say contentmapper.yml, every time to see what entity to grab based on the TypeId of the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestion from **@Cerad** about using class table inheritance (mapped superclass was used previously).

As I have a class which most of my entities extend (`BaseEntity`), including those which implement `SluggableInterface`, I set up a relation in the `MenuItem` to an object of `BaseEntity` - this allows any subclass to be used too.

To make sure only instances of `SluggableInterface` are related, I type-hint in the setter (e.g. `public function setRelatedEntity(SluggableInterface $entity)...`.